# Vue and TypeScript required prop

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I added a required prop to my component class using `vue-property-decorator`, but when I tried using the component without the prop, I didn't see any console errors that indicate the required prop is missing. Why?

```js
export default class Test extends Vue {
  @Prop() private message!: string;
}
```

The following code yields no errors as expected:

```html
<test message="Hello" />
```

The following code should result in an error but doesn't:

```html
<test />
```

Comment: My guess is you can't make it private

Comment: Excuse me, what does it mean? @LoganMurphy

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I changed private to public, but nothing's changed.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I hope there is an error like "Missing required prop". but there isn't any error.

Comment: `@Prop(String) readonly message!: string;`

Comment: @mira It is considering Hello as variable instead of value so convert it to string 'Hello'. or you should pass it without v-binding ':'

Comment: It is hard to believe you're not getting any errors from this code. I mean, if you aren't, chances are your code is not actually parsed. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`@Prop`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/blob/dbcb3a9/src/vue-property-decorator.ts#L159) decorator takes a [`PropOptions`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/59860b0a756526f37468655598c68d119f0e74bd/src/core/util/props.js#L17) object, which contains a `required` property with a default value of `false`. To make `message` required, specify `required: true` in your `@Prop` declaration:

```js
@Prop({ required: true }) private message!: string;
```

[image: Edit Vue Template]